# error when 3d graphics with knitr and rgl

Tags: r, webgl, knitr, rgl

I am trying to include an interactive plot in my htlm output using knitr and rgl. I have had success in the past but I am now unable to produce graphics from standard examples. When I run the code below my output includes the error "Your browser does not support WebGL. See http://get.webgl.org". When I check if it is supported my browser works fine with others interactive graphics.

any help would be appreciated, I may be making a simple mistake.

````
---
output:
  html_document:
    keep_md: yes
---
```
```{r setup, results='asis'}
library(rgl)
library(knitr)
knit_hooks$set(webgl = hook_webgl)
```

```{r testgl, webgl=TRUE}
x <- sort(rnorm(1000))
y <- rnorm(1000)
z <- rnorm(1000) + atan2(x,y)
plot3d(x, y, z, col=rainbow(1000))
```
````

Answer (score 2):

You don't say what version of rgl you are using.  There have been a lot of changes to it recently, so the version on R-forge is not compatible with knitr (at least the last time I looked).  I can't remember if the versions on CRAN are compatible.

Temporarily I'd recommend using the knitr hook that is contained in the rgl package (in https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/rgl/vignettes/setup.R?view=markup&root=rgl) if you are using the R-forge version.

Once things settle down I'll pass the necessary changes on to Yihui.

Edited to add:  The knitr hook function is now exported from rgl (as rgl::hook_webgl). This is on CRAN.  Still only on R-forge, the hook will be automatically installed if knitr is loaded first.

A further edit:  Don't use hook_webgl, use the rglwidget() function.  This has been in the CRAN version of rgl for a while now.